# Google sheets data to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to build a chartjs based on data from google sheets. After a long struggle and reading through numerous threads here, I still haven't been able to get my data through to javascript on my html file to be used for the chart.

I've put the followng code in my code.gs project in google script editor:

```
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {

  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(2000);  // wait 5 seconds before conceding defeat.

try {
  var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service
// get the chart data to pass through to front-end

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("HERE IS MY SPREADSHEET ID");
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("TestSheet");

  var headings = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].map(function(heading) {
    return heading.toLowerCase();
  });

  Logger.log(headings);

  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-3, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var data = [];
  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      obj[headings[j]] = values[i][j];
    }
    data.push(obj);
  }
  Logger.log(data);
  return data;

} catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

This gives the following execution transcript:

```
[18-04-12 20:23:51:233 PDT] Starting execution
[18-04-12 20:23:51:288 PDT] Lock.waitLock([2000]) [0.046 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:290 PDT] PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() [0.001 
seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:407 PDT] 
SpreadsheetApp.openById([HERE IS MY SPREADSHEET ID]) 
[0.116 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:408 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([TestSheet]) [0 
seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:707 PDT] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.299 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:708 PDT] Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 1, 2]) [0 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:808 PDT] Range.getValues() [0.099 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:810 PDT] Logger.log([[actor, income], []]) [0 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:51:906 PDT] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.095 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:52:004 PDT] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.098 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:52:006 PDT] Sheet.getRange([2, 1, 3, 2]) [0.001 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:52:006 PDT] Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:52:008 PDT] Logger.log([[{actor=Robert Downey, income=80.0}, 
{actor=Jackie Chan, income=50.0}, {actor=Vin Diesel, income=47.0}], []]) [0 
seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:52:073 PDT] Lock.releaseLock() [0.065 seconds]
[18-04-12 20:23:52:075 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.834 seconds total 
runtime]
```

So the google sheet side seems to work and is deployed as webapp. I have also another similar function to feed the data into a another sheet and that is working fine (different code of course on a different google script project).

When I call this macro from my script file as follows:

```
var request;
        console.log("before execute");
window.onload = callGoogleScript;
function callGoogleScript() {
    request = $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
        url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/MY MACRO ID/exec",
        type: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
        });

        console.log("Trying this:", request);
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        console.log(response);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });

        console.log("After execute");

}
```

The execution does not pop-up in google scripts logs, and I get the following error message in Chrome console:

```
before execute
results.html:96 Trying this: {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, 
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
results.html:105 After execute
results.html:1 Refused to execute script from 
'https://script.google.com/macros/s/HERE IS MY MACRO ID/exec? 
callback=jQueryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' because its MIME type 
('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Could you please help me out solving what is the missing key here? I've tried several solutions from other threads, but can't seem to get even a simple read script to work properly. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that jsonp is the data type that is being returned?

Comment: Not sure how exactly to do that.. Already tried several methods to get the data out as JSON, but no success.. Could you help me with the code, so that the "return data" is in JSON?

Comment: I changed the google script last part "return data" to return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);                                            and I can see in the execution transcript that:                                         [18-04-14 08:30:17:118 HKT] TextOutput.setMimeType([JSON]) [0 seconds]                                                                                                       However I still get the same MIME error in my Chrome console when trying to call the google script

Comment: I tweaked the google output again:   return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(values))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);                                      after which the execution log says: ContentService.createTextOutput([[[80],[50],[47],[41.5],[41],[99],[""]]]) [0 seconds]
[18-04-16 00:03:11:193 PDT] TextOutput.setMimeType([JSON]) [0 seconds]                                                                                                    BUT STILL calling the AJAX query (datatype = JSONP) returns MIME error... any clue how to get this simple string over?

Comment: I guess my question went to the point that JSON is not JSONP - they are two different but related data types. If you are outputting JSON and expecting JSONP maybe that is where the problem lies?